# How to compare JavaScript objects which contain cyclic object

Tags: javascript

Please tell me to compare JavaScript objects which contains cyclic object.

As follows,return true because a1 equals a2.

```
a1   = {}
a1.b = 1
a1.c = 2
a1.d = a

a2 = {}
a2.b = 1
a2.c = 2
a2.d = a2
```

As follows,return false because a1 does not equal a2.

```
a1   = {}
a1.b = 1
a1.c = 2
a1.d = a

a2 = {}
a2.b = 1
a2.c = 2
a2.d = a2
a2.e = a2
```

Comment: How are you comparing these two Object?

Comment: @Sushil That's his question

Comment: I mistaken the question

Comment: @Sushil Yes,Comparing these two Objects.

Comment: JSON has no way to express recursive data. You don't have JSON. These are JavaScript objects.

Comment: You are right.Thank you for editing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wYCbn/1/)

```
    var a1   = {}
a1.b = 1
a1.c = 2
a1.d = a1

var a2 = {}
a2.b = 1
a2.c = 2
a2.d = a2

function isSame(a,b){
    var same = true;
    if(a === b){
       return true;
    }
    for(var i in a){

        if(typeof a[i] == "object" ){
           if( a[i] == a){
                continue;
            }
           same = isSame(a[i], b[i]);
           if(same == false){
              return same;
           }
        }
       if(a[i] !== b[i])
       return false;
    }
   return true
}

console.log(isSame(a1, a2) );
```

Comment: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. I guess, OP has a typo: `a1.d = a1`

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev Fixed check fiddler

Comment: @Suhil Now it returns `false`, but meant to return `true` in that case.

Comment: `false` can be achieved with simple `===` comparison. OP wants to get `true`

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev My solution will return true if both object have same properties

Comment: My friend told me this solution.

Comment: @user2111479 Try now I fixed the way you want.

Comment: push objects checked into a working array and compare the index of object.

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a `Comparer` function, that suits your needs. However, it has a restriction, that first argument should have more properties than the second. I could switch them inside the `function` but I don't think it is good to create temporary object for that.
Also, it will return `false` in case:

```
a1.d = a2
a2.d = a1
```

Tell me if you need to handle that case too.


[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wYCbn/6/)

**EDIT:** I just got an idea, that you'd always get a stack size exception, when comparing cycling object, so you can `try catch` on this exception, but it probably will have a bad performance.
[**TRY CATCH EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wYCbn/7/)

Comment: Thank you and excuse me.I'm developing testing tool.

Its concept is "Without coding test, test automation for JavaScript."

https://github.com/puriketu99/porky

That's why I need to compare them but I withholded it once.